# tomcat 5.5 && Apache 2.2.3 (Windows XP) Integration

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

I'm trying to integrate `tomcat 5.5` and `apache 2.2.3` on windows xP (have to use it) . I've download the latest `mod_jk.so` and placed in into `modules` folder of apache.

Following additions/changes were made to `httpd.conf` :

```
ServerName localhost:8160
Listen 8160 

#load module
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

<IfModule jk_module>
        JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties

        JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log

        JkLogLevel debug

        JkShmFile logs/mod_jk.shm

        JkWatchdogInterval 60

        JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "

        JkMount /jsp-examples/*.jsp worker1

        JkMount /servlets-examples/* worker1
 </IfModule>
```

and created `workers.properties` which contains:

```
worker.list=worker1

# Set properties for worker1 (ajp13)
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8165
```

in tomcat `server.xml` :

```
<Connector port="8165" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

To begin i was trying to load the default webapps that ship with tomcat 5.5. `http://localhost:8165/servlets-examples/` works fine , `localhost:8160` shows "It works!" but trying 'http://localhost:8160/servlets-examples/' gives me a long wait and then

```
 Bad Gateway

 The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
```

trying `http://localhost:8160/jsp-examples` gives:

```
 The requested URL /jsp-examples was not found on this server.
```

Here's the link to `mod_jk.log` : http://pastie.org/2766089

anyone see what i've done wrong?

Comment: Do you really want to use mod_jk?  It's only really worth the hassle for very high volume sites. Most of the time mod_proxy is fine, and much easier to configure.

Comment: i realize it's tedious to configure but i have to use be using mod_jk to keep as close as possible to a production environment that uses mod_jk.

Comment: What might go wrong is the path linking files in windows system. For example, "JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties" suggest that tomcat config workers.properties is under the same folder of your apache config folder which is a bit strange, unless you declare alias somewhere. If you copy the config from a linux box to windows, you may want to double check that.

Comment: The problem was that i needed to include the full path for the JKWorkersFile. that seems to have done the trick. Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the comments and further research, i needed to include the full path to the `JkWorkersFile` and other JK* entries. so instead of having `JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties`... I modified the entries in httpd.conf as:

```
LoadModule    jk_module  c:/apache-5.5/modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile c:/apache-5.5/conf/workers.properties
JkShmFile     c:/apache-5.5/logs/mod_jk.shm
JkLogFile     c:/apache-5.5/logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel debug
```

and that seems to have done the trick.

Cheers.